# RemoveFromSelection(Item) does not stop rules being applied to the item

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to remove an E-Mail from my selection after a rule is applied, so the next rule doesn't check this E-Mail again.

But after using RemoveFromSelection, it still goes through it in the next loop.

```vb
For Each Rule In Rules
    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
                    
        ' Testing Rules here and if it fits I want to remove the Item
         Application.ActiveExplorer.RemoveFromSelection (Item)
                        
    Next Item
 Next Rule
```

Comment: Rules run on folders. You may have better luck moving the item to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `RemoveFromSelection` method in the loop is not really a good idea. You don't let the OS/Outlook to remove the item from the section. Here is what the [Explorer.RemoveFromSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.removefromselection) method says:

> If the specified item is selected, calling RemoveFromSelection will cause the SelectionChange event to fire. If the item is not selected, calling RemoveFromSelection will not cause the SelectionChange event to fire.

So, the UI should be updated to remove the item from the selection. To wait until is excluded I'd suggest using the [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) function which yields execution so that the operating system can process other events.